# Executing Talend Job .sh file in Airflow - Error as Bash command failed

Tags: airflow, talend

I am using Windows Subsytem for Linux

Copied the talend job folder from D drive using command: `cp -R /mnt/d/path /home/path`

Changed `.sh` file permission using command: `chmod 777 abc.sh` 
bash command: `"/home/path/abc.sh "` 
also tried bash command with: `'{{"/home/path/abc.sh"}}'`

Manually Executing task as : `airflow test abc123 abc123 2020-07-12`

Need help if I am missing some step

Comment: Can you please post complete error

Comment: Are you able to run you talend bash script ? I would start with that. Then paste your code for the airflow dag. I have done this using docker and kubernetes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# this import is used to instantiate dag
from airflow import DAG
# this import is used to run the tasks
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#Passing the sh file
execute_command = "/path/execute_sql_script_file_run.sh "
# this is the arguments used by the bash operator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'abc',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 7, 12),
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catchup': False
}
# instantiate a DAG
dag = DAG(
    'abc123', default_args=default_args,schedule_interval="@once")
#task are given some specific arguments we can also override the default_args here.
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='abc123',
    bash_command=execute_command,
    dag=dag)
```

Actually it needs to copy the whole TalendJob folder(conatins all jar files/libs) which was exported using Build.
This worked for me.

Thanks